# How to make docker.service wait for cni0.netdev bridge during systemd boot?

Tags: systemd, docker, bridge, systemd-networkd

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I have created a `cni0.netdev` and `cni0.network` file in `/etc/systemd/network` to create a virtual bridge to use for a local Kubernetes cluster/node.

I have enabled `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

I have the following in `docker.service` `[Unit]`:

```
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket
```

However, when I start up, `dockerd` complains that `cni0` isn't yet up, yet when I log in, the bridge is there. If I restart `dockerd` it picks up the bridge and uses it.

I can't add a `After=` for `cni0.netdev` because `netdev` files are configuration files for `systemd-networkd` and not "units" on their own.

It seems like `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` just waits for "any" interface to be online, which would be the regular `eth0` interface.

How can I wait for this bridge to be up and configured before `dockerd` is started?

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try to add a `After/Wants=sys-devices-virtual-net-cni0.device`

You can check the exact name of the device using `systemctl`

Comment: OK, I should try that.